# MCL clustering.

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-algorithm

I have implemented Markov clustering in python. Now when i run it on large graphs , clusters become non-deterministic. Would you please explain why does it happen and what should I do ?

```
import networkx as nx
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def normalize(M,colsum,nodes):
    for i in range(0,nodes):
        for j in range(0,nodes):
            if colsum[j] != 0 :
                M[i][j] = M[i][j] / colsum[j]

def converge(M,nodes):
    for i in range(nodes):
        for j in range(nodes):
            if M[i][j] == 0 :
                continue
            else :
                if M[i][j] != 1:
                    return 0
    return 1

G = nx.Graph()


#File which contains Adj Matrix , you need to change it with your filename
filename = "adjacency.txt"
f = open(filename)
lines = f.readlines() #reading lines from file

for i in lines:
    token = i.split()  #Splitting our string 
    if len(token) != 0 : #Edge Case
        G.add_edge(token[0],token[1]) #Adding edge

nodes = G.number_of_nodes()

A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A = A.toarray()

#Adding Self Loops 
for i in range(0,nodes):
    A[i][i] = 1

csum = A.sum(axis = 0)
A = A.tolist()
#Normalizing matrix
normalize(A,csum,nodes)

A = np.array(A)

count = 0
while(True):
    count = count + 1 
    A = np.linalg.matrix_power(A,2) #expansion
    A = np.power(A,2) #Inflation
    colsum = A.sum(axis = 0)
    normalize(A,colsum,nodes)
    #printing intermediate states
    print(count)
    print(A)
    if converge(A,nodes) == 1 :
        break 

#Stores Clusters
clusters = []

for i in range(nodes):
    temp = []
    for j in range(nodes):
        if A[i][j] == 1 :
            temp.append(j)
    if len(temp) != 0 :
        clusters.append(temp)

print(clusters)
```

Works fine for graphs with nodes < 50 but in case of large graphs clusters tend to change at each run.

Comment: If you are using python3, than there are some issues mentioning non-deterministic behaviour in networkx due to hash-salting. I don't know if all of these are fixed or if these are the reason for your problem. [Have a look](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+deterministic+is%3Aclosed).